# How do you make android buttons behave like a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make all the buttons in a layout view show at the bottom of the screen like in a toolbar fashion, with all buttons equally using the available space and a string of text in the center of the screen.

Am struggling to get the correct layout:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:baselineAligned="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/textView1"></TextView>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="187dp">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03"  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="Button"  android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="Button"  android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a bunch of things going on.  First off, it should be fill_parent and not match_parent.  Your outer LinearLayout you had set up as horizontal instead of vertical as well.   Also, as CommonsWare mentioned, use the 0dp + 1 weight to evenly space things.  Here's a modified layout that i think is close to what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:baselineAligned="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/textView1"></TextView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="187dp">
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Button"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

JUst a quick fix and you'll have to tweak more, but that's the idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm a complete newbie hence the mess. I thought match_parent is the same as fill_parent if you are using newer APIs?

Comment: You are correct, but I always use fill_parent for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @SBerg413: `fill_parent` and `match_parent` resolve to the same value. Runtime backwards compatibility, therefore, is not an issue. Using `fill_parent` will mean you can compile your code against an older SDK, before `match_parent` was defined, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_width="0dip"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for all of your `Button` widgets to have them be equally sized within the horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Comment: thanks for your answer too, I never know which answer to mark as answered when there are 2!